# Can we query 'show object' in snowflake with a where clause?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want something like this :
select * from (show stages) where storage_integration='xyz'. I am guessing this ain't possible. Is there an equivalent which would help me use the result set of show object in snowflake like a table result set which I can query? I am aware of the last query id() thing, want something else though!

Answer (score 1):

The last query id is the only way to do this.

```
show stages;
select * FROM  table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where storage_integration = 'xyz';
```

Comment: This makes it very inconvenient while writing stored procs, as I can't really perform many operations! Can't understand why snowflake didn't really give this as a usual select operation.